# Chebyshev theorem bounds

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Suppose the mean noon-time temperature for September days in San Diego is 24∘ and the standard deviation is 4.6. (Temperature in this problem is measured in degrees celsius)

Using Chebyshev’s theorem, what is the minimal probability (in percents) that the noon-time temperature of a september days is between 14.8∘ and 33.2∘?

On September 26, 1963, the all-time record of noon-time temperature in San Diego of 44∘ was hit. Assume the temperature distribution is symmetric around the mean, what is the Chebyshev bound for the probability of breaking (or tieing) this record?

I am a confused on how to start on this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

The first step (after reading the problem) is to write down the Chebyshev Inequality, carefully:
$$\Pr(|X-\mu|\ge k\sigma)\le \frac{1}{k^2}.$$
Here $\mu=24$ and $\sigma=4.6$.

Our interval is symmetrical about $24$, from $9.2$ below $\mu$ to $9.2$ above $\mu$. So we will be working with $k\sigma=9.2$. But $\sigma=4.6$, so $k=2$. They are being nice to us.

Now read carefully what the Chebyshev Inequality says, and the problem will be solved.

For the second problem, the symmetry assumption together with the Chebyshev Inequality implies that
$$\Pr(X-\mu\ge k\sigma)\le \frac{1}{2k^2}.$$ 
You will need to compute the appropriate $k$.